# When I write a Flutter plugin, how can I get the android.app.Application object？

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, flutter-dependencies

When I use Flutter to develop my application, I need use a third-party android SDK.

This SDK needs to init very early before I use other SDK functions and this init function has params which are Application object from android.app.Application.

But how can I get this application object in my plugin.java file so that I can use it to define a function that I can use?

Someone told me that there is an `import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;` class, but it's uneditable, and even if I could edit it, I have nowhere to use it, so I still can't init my SDK.

Here is what I'm thinking, but it's not good enough:

```java
public class FlutterApplication extends Application {
    ....
    @CallSuper
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MySDK.init(this_application_object, param1, param2)
        FlutterMain.startInitialization(this);
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: You'd normally have to provide instructions for your plugin user to call this initialisation in their app. See the instructions for `firebase_messaging` as an example. In your plugin, you'd do this in the `example/android` app. In `onCreate()` just use `getApplication()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the application context like this...

```
public class CloudSdkPlugin implements MethodCallHandler {

    private static Context context;

     public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
        context=registrar.activity().getApplication();

      }
    }
```

Comment: Same scenario need to create a payment plugin in flutter for Android.

First user need to initialise the payment sdk with token when navigating to payment
After that user will able to make a payment previously initialised object